# Missing claims in ClaimsPrincipal in the Resource/API Server protected with OpenIddict

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-7.0, openiddict

I have OpenIddict server with the usual configuration (Server.csproj):

```cs
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options => ...)
    .AddServer(options => ...)
    .AddValidation(options => ...)
    .AddUIStore(options => ...)
    .AddUIApis(options => ...)
```

And I have another Resource/API server protected with OpenIddict Client library (Api.csproj):

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.SetIssuer("...");
        options
            .UseIntrospection()
            .SetClientId("xxx")
            .SetClientSecret("xxx");
        options.UseSystemNetHttp();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });
```

In the API server, when someone calls the API method `MyGetMethod`, the user is correctly authenticated.

```
[HttpGet()]
[Authorize(Policy = "DefaultPolicy")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyGetMethod()
{
    var accessToken = await this.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    var isAuthenticated = this.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated;
    ...
}
```

But I don't have my custom claims passed in the access token inside the `ClaimsPrincipal`.

Here is the access token content from the variable `accessToken` using Jwt.io:

```json
{
  "sub": "user@xxx.xxx",
  "name": "Adrien Pellegrini",
  "email": "xxx@xxx.xxx",
  "employeeId": xxx,  <===============
  "username": "user",
  "given_name": "Adrien",
  "family_name": "Pellegrini",
  "office_location": "xxx",  <===============
  "role": "a_super_role",  <===============
  "oi_prst": "MyClientId",
  "client_id": "MyClientId",
  "oi_tkn_id": "0edc928b-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxe9ca",
  "scope": "openid profile email roles offline_access",
  "jti": "f9d386bf-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx29fa",
  "exp": 1686050931,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5001/",
  "iat": 1686047331
}
```

Here is the list of claims I get from the `ClaimsPrincipal.Claims`:

```
"sub: user@xxx.xxx"
"jti: 9dbd9460-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx34423"
"token_usage: access_token"
"client_id: MyClientId"
"iat: 1686053762"
"exp: 1686057362"
"oi_tkn_typ: access_token"
"oi_crt_dt: Tue, 06 Jun 2023 12:16:02 GMT"
"oi_exp_dt: Tue, 06 Jun 2023 13:16:02 GMT"
"oi_prst: MyClientId"
```

I would like to have the `"employeeId", "username", "given_name", "family_name", "office_location", "role"` inside the claims.

There is a way with a custom validation handler `ValidationHandler` / `ValidateTokenContext`:

```cs
public class MyEventHandler : IOpenIddictValidationHandler<ValidateTokenContext>
{
    public static OpenIddictValidationHandlerDescriptor Descriptor { get; }
        = OpenIddictValidationHandlerDescriptor.CreateBuilder<ValidateTokenContext>()
            .UseScopedHandler<MyEventHandler>()
            .SetType(OpenIddictValidationHandlerType.Custom)
            .Build();

    public ValueTask HandleAsync(ValidateTokenContext context)
    {
        var principal = context.Principal;
        // use and parse context.Token
        return default;
    }
}
```

But I still need to parse the token manually to have the required information.

Is there a proper way to include "custom claims"?

Answer (score 0):

Two conditions are required for application claims to be returned by OpenIddict via introspection:

- The caller MUST be a confidential application.
- The caller MUST have its `client_id` listed as a valid audience (i.e it must be included when calling `principal.SetResources(...)`).

Take a look at the logs to confirm it's indeed the root cause and make sure you call `principal.SetResources(...)` with a list that contains the `client_id` of your resource server (you can use a `scope` for that).